# combine ping with a background process

Tags: bash, background-process, job-control

What am I doing wrong here?

```
(sleep 2; touch /tmp/ok) & && ping google.com
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
```

I'm using bash 3.2

Comment: `&` is a command separator. `&&` is a different command separator. You can only use one of them at a time. (The only exception to that is the newline, which is legal even if preceded by a different/explicit one).

Comment: And `&&` doesn't make sense in the context of having something in the background on the left: The code on the right doesn't have any way of knowing whether the thing on the left succeeded or not, since they're starting at the same time.

Comment: ...so, it needs to be just `command1 & command2`, not `command1 & && command2` or `command1 &; command2`.